# Casting integer type on hexadecimal already formatted as string in Java

Tags: java, sql, hex, prepared-statement

I have long (32 characters + leading 0x) hexadecimal value stored as string:

```
String key = '0x000639847445EB1570C9D9C92DAA1FB8'
```

For this to work, my query should look like this:

```
Select * from table where key = 0x000639847445EB1570C9D9C92DAA1FB8
```

It used to work with normal SQL statements but we changed it to Prepared Statement:

```
setString(preparedStatement, 1, key);
```

As we have the value in string, this is what it produces:

```
Select * from table where key = '0x000639847445EB1570C9D9C92DAA1FB8'
```

and our query does not return anything. Basically, I need to 'extract' the value from string format and apply another type to it without messing up the value, so my final query would have such format:

```
 Select * from table where key = 0x000639847445EB1570C9D9C92DAA1FB8
```

I have tried Byte.parseByte, adding this value to BigInt, however nothing seems to give result I'm looking for.

Comment: Given that your value is outside the range of `long`, I'd suggest using `BigInteger` instead - parse the string value to a `BigInteger`, then use `PreparedStatement.setObject`.

Comment: Actually the value is nowhere near approaching Long.MAX_VALUE so setLong could be used. As long as the value never exceeds 16 bytes in size, you should be fine (as long as keys can be negative numbers too)

Comment: modify the SQL statement with  key = convert(varbinary(16), ? ,1),  as the resulting convert(varbinary(16),'0x000639847445EB1570C9D9C92DAA1FB8',1) will generate the 16 bytes binary value